# MYSQL Select Case Row to Column

Tags: mysql

helo,
I'm trying to transpose a column named element_label from table wp_formmaker_submits.

The original table is

```
+---------+---------------+------------------+----------+
| FORM_ID | ELEMENT_LABEL |    ELEMENT_VALUE | GROUP_ID |
+---------+---------------+------------------+----------+
|      10 |             1 |       18-11-2014 |        1 |
|      10 |             2 |         Logistic |        1 |
|      10 |             3 | Warehouse Supply |        1 |
|      10 |             4 |              Red |        1 |
|      10 |             1 |       19-11-2014 |        2 |
|      10 |             2 |   Transportation |        2 |
|      10 |             3 |          Vehicle |        2 |
|      10 |             4 |            Green |        2 |
+---------+---------------+------------------+----------+
```

I'm using this query

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN element_label = 1 THEN element_value END a1,
CASE WHEN element_label = 2 THEN element_value END a2,
CASE WHEN element_label = 3 THEN element_value END a3,
CASE WHEN element_label = 4 THEN element_value END a4
FROM wp_formmaker_submits
```

and my result is

```
+------------+----------------+------------------+--------+
|         A1 |             A2 |               A3 |     A4 |
+------------+----------------+------------------+--------+
| 18-11-2014 |           NULL |             NULL |   NULL |
|       NULL |       Logistic |             NULL |   NULL |
|       NULL |           NULL | Warehouse Supply |   NULL |
|       NULL |           NULL |             NULL |    Red |
| 19-11-2014 |           NULL |             NULL |   NULL |
|       NULL | Transportation |             NULL |   NULL |
|       NULL |           NULL |          Vehicle |   NULL |
|       NULL |           NULL |             NULL |  Green |
+------------+----------------+------------------+--------+
```

How to remove the NULL, so i'll get the result like this

```
+---------+----------+------------+----------------+------------------+-------+
| FORM_ID | GROUP_ID |         A1 |             A2 |               A3 |    A4 |
+---------+----------+------------+----------------+------------------+-------+
|      10 |        1 | 18-11-2014 |       Logistic | Warehouse Supply |   Red |
|      10 |        2 | 19-11-2014 | Transportation |          Vehicle | Green |
+---------+----------+------------+----------------+------------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT form_id,group_id,
MAX(CASE WHEN element_label = 1 THEN element_value END) as a1,
MAX(CASE WHEN element_label = 2 THEN element_value END) as a2,
MAX(CASE WHEN element_label = 3 THEN element_value END) as a3,
MAX(CASE WHEN element_label = 4 THEN element_value END) as a4
FROM tbl
Group by form_id,group_id
```

if still having issues then plz share your table schema on sqlfiddle.

Comment: Request you to add `MAX` function before `CASE`.

Comment: it is working fine. as it is generating the result accordingly, and using MAX is not generating the required results

Answer (score 1):

add an aggregate function, eg

```
MAX(CASE WHEN element_label = 1 THEN element_value END) a1
```